# DC Motor Time to Attain Full Speed Formula Origin

Tags: dc-motor, torque

[image]

There is no formal discussion but I see a formula that relates the average available torque to moment of inertia in problems from Electrical Technology by Theraja. I have tried searching about this formula in the net but I only see straight up solutions as well.

Where did this formula come from and why loss torque is used and other discussions about the formula?

Comment: torque = (moment of inertia)(angular acceleration). Be sure to use MKS units consistently.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia

Comment: I almost failed my “drives” course because unlike real physics it was based largely on heuristics and taught by a pompous prof. This is starting to smell like heuristics to me, I hope your prof is nice.